# How can I properly interpret M4's $# variable without starting comment syntax in emacs?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, comments

I have the following M4 macro definition:

```
define(`printlist',`$1`'ifelse(`$#',1,,`printlist(shift($@))')')
```

`#` does begin a comment in M4 syntax, but only when it isn't preceded by a `$`: `$#` is the number of arguments the macro received.

How can I alter `m4-font-lock-keywords` to handle this appropriately?

The default value is:

```
(("\\(\\b\\(m4_\\)?dnl\\b\\|^\\#\\).*$" . font-lock-comment-face)
 ("\\$[*#@0-9]" . font-lock-variable-name-face)
 ("\\$\\@" . font-lock-variable-name-face)
 ("\\$\\*" . font-lock-variable-name-face)
 ("\\b\\(...\\)\\b" . font-lock-keyword-face))
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with emacs lisp, but can you do look-behind matching? Regular expressions can do things like this `/(?<!\$)#/` to match instances of `#` without a `$` preceding it.

Comment: You may wish to comment out `(modify-syntax-entry ?# "<\n" m4-mode-syntax-table)` and use an alternative method for highlighting comments -- e.g., adding a comment entry to the variable `m4-font-lock-keywords` instead of using the syntax table.

Comment: For those forum participants who may be interested viewing the source code for this major-mode, the following link likely contains the major-mode source code that is being used by the original poster:  http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/emacs/emacs-70/emacs/lisp/progmodes/m4-mode.el

Comment: @lawlist That's a partial fix: `(modify-syntax-entry ?# "@" m4-mode-syntax-table)` will work correctly for `/^#.*$/`, but will not work for `/.*#.*$/` (as far as actual comment syntax is concerned).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `#` can also begin a comment when preceded by `$`.  Whether `#` starts a comment or not depends on whether it's within quoted text or not.

You can try the code below to make Emacs (try to) follow m4's semantics more precisely:

```
(defun m4--quoted-p (pos)
  "Return non-nil if POS is inside a quoted string."
  (let ((quoted nil))
    (dolist (o (nth 9 (save-excursion (syntax-ppss pos))))
      (if (eq (char-after o) ?\`) (setq quoted t)))
    quoted))

(defconst m4-syntax-propertize
  (syntax-propertize-rules
   ("#" (0 (when (m4--quoted-p (match-beginning 0))
             (string-to-syntax "."))))))

(add-hook 'm4-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'syntax-propertize-function)
                          m4-syntax-propertize)))
```

Note that `syntax-propertize-function` only exists in sufficiently recent versions of Emacs (>=24.1, IIRC).